# Meromorphic function on a compact Riemann surface with single simple pole does not exist

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

> Let $P$ be a point in a compact Riemann surface $M$ of positive genus $g>0$. Then there does not exist a holomorphic function $f$ on $M\setminus\{P\}$ with a simple pole at $P$.

The statement is written like a trivial fact in Farkas & Kra Riemann surface textbook with a simple explanation: *Since $g>0$*.
I think it's from Riemann-Roch theorem (what else I can do?). So we consider $P$ as a divisor on $M$. Then the statement is equivalent to saying that $r(P^{-1}) = r(1) = 1$. From Riemann-Roch,
$$r(P^{-1}) = \deg P - g+1+i(P) = 2-g+i(P).$$
So the statement is equivalent to saying that $i(P) =0$, i.e., there is no holomorphic differential with degree $\geq 1$ at $P$. I can't see why this is true.

Comment: Assuming $g>0$ consider the spaces $L_k$ of functions of a pole of order at most $k$ at $P$ and no other poles. Riemann-Roch tells you that for large enough $k$ we have $\dim L_k=k+1-g$. This implies that there exists a natural number $\ell$ such that $L_\ell=L_{\ell+1}$. What is the smallest such $\ell$? If $L_1$ is strictly larger than $L_0$, then there exists a function $f$ with a simple pole only. Multiplication by $f$ gives an injective mapping from $L_k$ into $L_{k+1}$ for all $k$. Furthermore, the constant function is not in the image. This implies that the smallest $\ell$ must be zero.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that the argument, based on so called *gaps*, is common enough to have been covered on our site already. Alas, I don't frequent any of the relevant tags, so I don't know the buzzwords to base a search on. I learned the argument when studying the application of algebraic geometry into coding theory! It never ceases to amaze me how connected various parts of math and its applications are!